Advice of @Conditional aspect configured via XML always executing
I want to conditionally create an Aspect depending on a value read from the properties file. (It is related to profiling, that's why the intended selective use).
I have tried to create a class that implements Condition and therefore the matches() method that would allow me to perform the validation necessary and set the output to the corresponding Boolean, enabling or disabling it.
@Aspect
@Component
@Conditional(AuthFilterCondition.class)
public class AuthTokenFilter {

    @Before("@annotation(org.company.annotations.ValidateAuthToken)")
    public void doBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Loading auth token filter");

    }
}

AuthFilterCondition
public class AuthFilterCondition implements Condition {

    private static final String IS_AUTH_FILTER_FEATURE_ENABLED = "org.company.load.auth.filter";

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return (context.getEnvironment().getProperty(IS_AUTH_FILTER_FEATURE_ENABLED).equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
    }
}

Controller
@Path("/v1")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public interface HealthService {

    @GET
    @Path("/check/health")
    Response checkHealth();
}

ServiceImpl
public class HealthServiceImpl implements HealthService {

    @ValidateAuthToken
    @Override
    public Response checkHealth() {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}

servercontext.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
            base-package="org.company" />
    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:/META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <import
        resource="classpath*:META-INF/rcp/soa-interceptor-context.xml" />
    <bean id="healthService"
          class="org.company.services.impl.HealthServiceImpl" />
    <bean class="org.company.services.filter.AuthTokenFilter" lazy-init="true">
   
     <jaxrs:server address="/services">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="healthService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
</beans>

I'm already using an Aspect with Component to be detected during the component scan and the advise to be skipped if not matched, but it is still executing advise. Please suggest if I am doing something wrong here.
Here, I am passing a VM argument while running this which has the below value which will make AuthFilterCondition work.
-Dorg.company.load.auth.filter=true 


This works just fine here. Probably, the problem is in the code not shown here, e.g. in AuthFilterCondition. It is kind of hard to reason about invisible code. Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, ideally a GitHub project. Thank you. BTW, if your condition is not super complicated but just true or false, have you considered using @ConditionalOnProperty?

@kriegaex I have tried adding all the related files with respect to this. Have tried every way to make this work but the before advise still executes.

You edited the question, thanks. Not having tried your full example yet but just your AuthFilterCondition, in I see no reason why the aspect would always execute. In my own sample project, it does not. I just changed the class to also work when the property is unset, i.e. String isAuthFilterEnabled = context.getEnvironment().getProperty(IS_AUTH_FILTER_FEATURE_ENABLED); return isAuthFilterEnabled != null && isAuthFilterEnabled.equalsIgnoreCase("true");. As expected, the aspect is activated and deactivated depending on the system property value.

Are you sure you are not setting org.company.load.auth.filter anywhere else, e.g. a forgotten test line in your main class, doing something like System.setProperty("org.company.load.auth.filter", "true"); before creating the application context, effectively overriding the JVM command line parameter? I asked for a full project on GitHub for a reason.

@kriegaex I do not see the beans for other classes where AuthFilterCondition is applied and is working absolutely fine. Just this AuthFilterToken is getting loaded always. Let me try adding the property as you mentioned.

Do yourself a favour and publish an MCVE on GitHub. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum - too many comments already, including my own.

@kriegaex Please find MCVE here

The MCVE has no main class, and I am not a regular Spring user who keeps a stand-alone application server around all the time. Would you mind turning the project into a Spring Boot application which I can just run after importing the Maven project into my IDE?

Looking further into your so-called reproducer, Maven cannot even find the sources because they are in a helloworld subfolder. A javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.1.0 version also cannot be found on Maven Central and HelloWorldService imports two conflicting Response classes. You definitely never tried to even compile this pseudo code. Please do better in your next commit and leave behind something that actually builds and runs. Besides, why create a new repository and put all code in a branch instead of the main branch that is checked out automatically after cloning?

@kriegaex I tried reproducing this in springboot app but it works there, no problem at all. But since I am currently working in spring app with jax-rs, and that too for an organisation so cannot make the code public. But something is wrong with the spring way of doing things. let me provide a fix for this temp repo.

@kriegaex This is MCVE for springboot app here - It is working absolutely fine.

Nobody needs your original code, a minimal reproducer like your Spring Boot project is fine. If you cannot create one, the problem probably is not in Spring but sitting in front of the computer. It happens to the best of us, but my working hypothesis for now is that you are overlooking something that is not part of your Spring Boot reproducer. I see no reason why in your setup the condition should work differently. I could be wrong of course, but then please prove it.

@kriegaex I have updated the MCVE here for spring. This issue is exactly reproducible with this code. You might want to take a look at this.

OK, I can reproduce it now when calling http://localhost:8080/helloworld/v1/check/health after deploying the WAR.

I am not sure, but maybe the reason in works in Boot is simply that it uses a more recent Spring version. You may want to experiment with that. Maybe, something was fixed or improved there. I am a bit too busy at the moment to play around with it myself, my timebox is up for today.

@kriegaex Thanks for investing time. I am guessing it should be made conditional in beans.xml file where we are defining AuthTokenFilter.java bean. Because that's the only thing different from springboot.

@kriegaex I tried something and it worked out. Basically instead of defining AuthTokenFilter bean in xml, i used java configuration to define it and applied conditional over that. It works like a charm.

Yes, of course! You defined the aspect via XML. I did not notice when reading the XML config, because there was no "Aspect" in its class name but "Filter", which activated a different pattern in my brain. There does not seem to be any equivalent to condition annotations in XML, but you could use a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and inject an enabled value into the aspect. But then, you could make the aspect detect the system property directly, too. Sorry, I next to never use XML config, only Spring annotations.

I spent a lot of time to discuss with you, research and write a comprehensive answer. There has been zero feedback from you. Please, be polite enough to accept and upvote the answer, if it addresses your problem adequately. Otherwise, feel free to comment and explain what is wrong with it or what you do not understand. Thank you.

Switching to annotation-based bean definitions like you did is probably the easiest solution. But if you have reasons to stick with XML, you could just use a Spring profile:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

  <beans profile="auth-filter">
    <bean class="org.company.service.filter.AuthTokenFilter" lazy-init="true"/>
  </beans>

  <beans>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.company"/>
    <bean id="helloWorldService" class="org.company.service.impl.HelloWordServiceImpl"/>
    <jaxrs:server id="restContainer" address="/">
      <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="helloWorldService"/>
      </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
  </beans>

</beans>

Please note <beans profile="auth-filter">.
Then, remove the @Component and @Conditional annotations from the aspect:
@Aspect
//@Component
//@Conditional(AuthFilterCondition.class)
public class AuthTokenFilter {
  public static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_HEADER = "accessToken";

  @Before("@annotation(org.company.service.annotation.ValidateAuthToken)")
  public void doBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("Reaching Aspect");
  }
}

You also do not need the AuthFilterCondition class anymore.
Next, e.g. on Windows when starting Tomcat, you can do this to activate the aspect:
xxx> set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=auth-filter
xxx> "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat"

To deactivate it, either never set the environment variable or unset it, if it is defined already:
xxx> set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=
xxx> "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat"

